# Swift: Outputting a CoreData fetched Array of Dictionaries to a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

So what I'm basically trying to achieve is displaying **a list of (distinct) categories** in a TableView. The categories are fetched from CoreData, and alphabetically sorted and filtered on distinction by means of `fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true`. The output of the fetch is an array of dictionaries:

```
(
        {
        category = Bread;
    },
        {
        category = Cheese;
    },
        {
        category = Vegetables;
    }
)
```

I'm having some problems outputting these category values to my TableView, as `var distinctResults` outputs as **nil** everywhere outside of `func fetchMaterial()`, resulting in: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at this part in the code:

```
return distinctResults!.count
```

How would I be able to set `distinctResults` to its correct value as set in `func fetchProduct()`? (assuming this is the best approach to solve this issue). A thousand thanks in advance! =)

This is my relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CategoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}()

var distinctResults: [String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchProduct()
}

func fetchProduct() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")

    // Create a sort descriptor object sorting on the "category" property of the Core Data object
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true)

    // Set the list of sort descriptor in the fest request so it includes the descriptor
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = NSArray(object: "category")
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

    var distinctResults: NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return distinctResults!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CategoryTableViewCell
    let distinctResult = distinctResults[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell
    cell.categoryLabel?.text = distinctResult

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Sure. `var distinctResults: NSArray = ...` assigns the result of the fetch request in to a local variable, and does not update the property `var distinctResults: [String]!`.

Comment: and in addition to @Martin ... var distinctResults: [String]! is an array of string and not a dictionary. it should be an array of anyobject:string like this : [AnyObject:String]

Comment: Thanks guys! The local variable not updating the property was indeed the main issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting your ivar `distinctResults`. In `fetchProduct`, you write

```
var distinctResults : NSArray = ...
```

Because of the keyword `var` you are declaring a new variable, the scope of which will be limited to the `fetchProduct` method. Once the method returns, the variable will be discarded.

Instead, you should assign the results to your existing variable

```
self.distinctResults = ...
```

I think there might be other problems with your code, but this is the answer to your question about the `nil` variable.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, your post provided a clear answer to the issue I was having regarding the nil variable =) As you mentioned I have a few more kinks to iron out in the code, but this was the main issue.